# Grails 2.2 to 2.3 - Error running forked test-app: Could not load grails build listener class

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-2.2, grails-2.3

I'm migrating my project from grails 2.2 to 2.3 and when I do test-app (on IDEA 12.1.6), I got this error

```
| Error Error running forked test-app: Could not load grails build listener class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load grails build listener class
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener.addGrailsBuildListener(GrailsBuildEventListener.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener.loadGrailsBuildListeners(GrailsBuildEventListener.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener.initialize(GrailsBuildEventListener.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.createEventListener(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.createInstance(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.initializeProjectInstance(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:85)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.run(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.main(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.groovy.grails.rt.GrailsIdeaTestListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:648)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:758)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:746)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener.addGrailsBuildListener(GrailsBuildEventListener.java:255)
    ... 7 more
| Error Error running forked test-app: Could not load grails build listener class
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

My BuildConfig.groovy look like this:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" 
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6

grails.project.fork = [
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" 
    checksums true 
    legacyResolve false 

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
    }

    plugins {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.42"

        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.2" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.2"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
    }
}
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Have you also tried without forked JVM?

Comment: Yeah "unforked" it works well, but I also wanna use the forked mode

Comment: Any update on this? Was a solution ever found?

Comment: I just try with 2.3.4 and I still have the exact same problem

Comment: There's a issue open at jetbrain http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-61453

Answer (score 8):

In order to take advantage of the new Grails fork test functionality in IntelliJ at the moment, you need to [find the grails-rt.jar file under your IntelliJ installation directory](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/02/grails-goodness-run-forked-tests-in.html), and copy it to your grails project lib dir, or make it available to your grails application via the class path.

In my case, on Mac OS X, the grails-rt.jar file was located in:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13.app/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-rt.jar
```

and I copied this file to `~/MyGrailsApp/lib`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this as soon as possible and I'll give you feedback ;)

Comment: This worked for me but it seems like it should be brought up in a JIRA ticket or bug report for intellij.

Comment: It looks like there are at least a couple of tickets: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115855, and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115097

Comment: As noted in the IDEA ticket @RyanGrow mentioned, you can set: grails.project.fork = [
    test: false,
    ...
]
in your BuildConfig as a workaround.